# advice for a better way to create an user activation link

Tags: apache-axis

I have made an axis 2 web service that sends email to users with some kind of activation link

when the user click on that activaion link - the active column in my postgresql should be updated 
0-----------------------------------------------

So  i decide as the easiest way should be to just add method uodatedb that updates this column and my activaton link is actually a link to mywebservice and its udatedb method
and loooks like

**

```
 " <a href=\"http://localhost/hashing_password/services/Hashing_Password/UpdateDB?choUUIID=" +uuid+"\">http://localhost:9091/Hashing_Passwords/services/Hashing_Password/UpdateDB?choUUIID=" +uuid+
```

and when I click on the link   I see a warn message that I'm redirected to a page with strange formatting that can contain viruses.

Is there a better way to create that activation link - without

Someone told me that I might create php proxy page but I haven't worked with php

Answer (score 0):

You link to `http://localhost/`, but the label of your link shows `http://localhost:9091/`. Maybe your browser thinks that this is a potential malicious link. Correct the link or use a more neutral label.